# I have mislabelled a herb (thought it was chives), can anyone recognize what this is?

Tags: identification, herbs

[image: Here's a photo of the plant]

Reddit thinks it might be a tomato. I thought it was chives, obviously it's not, but I still think I picked it from the herb shelf, not from a vegetable shelf.

Comment: It looks like a tomato to me also. However, the tiny green grass-like thing to the right of the tomato looks like chives :)

Comment: Yeah but the tiny green grass is doing absolutely nothing so far :D And this little "tree" that's growing is the only thing that's sprouted, and it's been over a month. We'll see :D

Comment: Well, chive sprouts are of very distinguishable form - search for chive sprouts on google images, for example this shows their specific form http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:WIkibooks_planting-chives_sprout.jpg. Also, you need to sow quite a lot of seeds, as individual chive plants are generally just one stem. How much seeds did you sow?

Comment: Quite a bit, surely more than 30 or so.

Comment: For a tomato it is missing the "initial" leaves, which do not at all have the form of the final leaves...

Comment: There are two leaves that are nothing like the final ones, but they're covered in the photo.

Answer (score 9):

It does look like a tomato. The easy way to tell for sure is to gently rub the leaves -- even at that size, tomato should have a distinctive aroma. If you used compost in your potting soil, you could just have gotten a volunteer from a stray seed.

As mentioned in the comments, the seedling to the right of the tomato could be a chive. They grow fairly slowly, so "doing absolutely nothing" is par for the course.

Comment: @eagerMoose did you try rubbing and smelling it per this suggestion?